# Closure error in R while producing plots in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to reproduce the following plot using the `UNvotes` SQLite data but encountering an error:

```
Error: Unknown input type: closure
```

[image: plot]

code:

```
library(RSQLite)
con <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), "unvotes.sqlite")
dbListTables(con)
unvotes_db <- tbl(con, "unvotes")
unvotes_db

# Number of resolution votes per year
joined <- unvotes_db %>%
  inner_join(unvotes_db, by = "rcid") 

library(lubridate)

by_country_year <- joined %>%
  group_by(year = year(date), country) %>%
  summarize(votes = n(),
            percent_yes = mean(vote == "yes"))

library(ggplot2)
theme_set(theme_bw())

countries <- c("United States of America", "China", "Japan")

by_country_year %>%
  filter(country %in% countries, year<=2021) %>%
  ggplot(aes(year, percent_yes, color = country)) +
  geom_line() +
  ylab("percentage_yes_votes")
```

Not sure whether it is the problem of the join that I am using or should I even subset the data.

From `dput`

```
> dput(head(unvotes_db))
structure(list(src = structure(list(con = new("SQLiteConnection", 
    ptr = <pointer: 0x000001e93b8700e0>, dbname = "C:\\Users\\User\\Downloads\\DSR\\unvotes.sqlite", 
    loadable.extensions = TRUE, flags = 70L, vfs = "", ref = <environment>, 
    bigint = "integer64", extended_types = FALSE), disco = NULL), class = c("src_SQLiteConnection", 
"src_dbi", "src_sql", "src")), ops = structure(list(name = "head", 
    x = structure(list(x = structure("unvotes", class = c("ident", 
    "character")), vars = c("rcid", "country", "country_code", 
    "vote")), class = c("op_base_remote", "op_base", "op")), 
    dots = list(), args = list(n = 6)), class = c("op_head", 
"op_single", "op"))), class = c("tbl_SQLiteConnection", "tbl_dbi", 
"tbl_sql", "tbl_lazy", "tbl"))
```

Pasting the `rlang::last_error()`

```
> rlang::last_error()
<error/rlang_error>
Unknown input type: closure
Backtrace:
  1. `%>%`(...)
  4. dbplyr:::group_by.tbl_lazy(., year = year(date), country)
  5. dplyr::group_by_prepare(.data, !!!dots, .add = .add)
  6. dplyr:::add_computed_columns(.data, new_groups, "group_by")
  8. dbplyr:::mutate.tbl_lazy(.data, !!!vars)
  9. dbplyr:::partial_eval_dots(dots, vars = op_vars(.data))
 10. base::lapply(dots, partial_eval_quo, vars = vars)
 11. dbplyr:::FUN(X[[i]], ...)
 12. dbplyr::partial_eval(get_expr(x), vars, get_env(x))
 13. dbplyr:::partial_eval_call(call, vars, env)
 14. base::lapply(call[-1], partial_eval, vars = vars, env = env)
 15. dbplyr:::FUN(X[[i]], ...)
```

Comment: in the filter, presumable you want year == 2021 or some other condition

Comment: Yeah, thanks for pointing out it was to be `2020` .

Comment: Does the code work now?

Comment: Nope, it seems the error comes from the line(s) written after `library(lubridate)`

Comment: Which line does the error come from exactly? Why there is only `year` in `filter` ? What happens when you remove `year` from it?

Comment: The error comes mainly after running `by_country_year` code chunk.

Comment: Without your data (`by_country_year`, NOT `unvotes_db`), we can only guess.  But `lubridate` has a `year` function.  If `ggplot` is using `lubridatye::year` rather than your `year` column, that would explain the error.  To fix, rename your `year` column or unload `lubridate`.

Comment: Where do you define `date`? It's a function in `lubridate`, so if it isn't a predefined variable, then `year(.)` will be called on a function (i.e., a closure) instead of a variable. (It may be defined in your frame, but the `dput` you provided doesn't help.

Comment: I changed from `sqlite` implementation to the `library(unvotes)`. It now works!